# Signal at a specific interval with a countdown timer

Tags: java, android, algorithm, timer, countdowntimer

Right now I have a CountDownTimer that ticks like this:

```
MyTimer(60000, 1);
```

So it ticks down 60 seconds with an interval of 1ms.
I am signaling bpm's in my timer.

This is done by dividing every minute by a bpm-number:

```
public void onTick(long millisLeft) {
    if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisLeft) % (60 / bpm) == 0) {
     doSignal();
    }
}
```

This works great, but ONLY if the timer is set to interval 1000

```
MyTimer(60000, 1000);
```

That means it will tick once every second (every 1000ms). But I need it to tick at 1ms.

The problem with my condition is that if the timer ticks at an interval of 1ms. It will start the signal when supposed to - but repeat rapidly.

If interval is 1000ms and bpm is set to 20, it will beep every third second (60/20 == 3). If the interval is set to 1ms, it will start beeping every third second - and beep repeatedly through that second.

So somehow my condition is true within a larger span than I intended with 1ms ticker interval.

**How do I design my condition so it will fire only once every (60 / bpm) seconds with the timer at an interval of 1ms?**

Answer (score 2):

`TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisLeft)` returns 57 for all `57000 <= millisLeft <= 57999` so within that second you get 1000 `doSignal` calls (as `57 % (60/20) == 0`). And the same goes on for 54, 51, ... . To avoid this you could use this expression instead `millisLeft % (60000/20) == 0`.

Comment: Thank you. I actually did try that from the start. But it seems the onTick behaves really weird then. Somehow the if-statement misses most of the times. It is as if it just doesn't make it in time. Back to the drawing board it seems. The reason I needed a 1ms tick is because I have a stack of timers that pops and runs. If the ticker is at 1000ms there is a small hiccup in the transition between timers (when the next timer is popped).

Comment: Not sure about the android timer, but at least [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) states that you do not get overlapping calls to `onTick`. If your `doSignal` takes longer than a ms this might cause missing ticks. In that case something like this could help: `Long signalledSecond = 0l;
    public void onTick(long millisLeft) {
        Long second = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisLeft+999);
        if (second % (60 / 20) == 0 && signalledSecond != second) {
            signalledSecond = second;
            doSignal();
        }
    }
`